# How to set only public key in OpenSSL 3.0 EVP_PKEY api

Tags: c++11, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I am able to extract public and private keys from OSSL_PARAM array with these functions. for RSA I extract parameter "n" for public key and "d" for private key
(i tried using special functions to get these parameters by these names, but they can't find them and fail for some reason)

```
std::vector<unsigned char> GetNamedParam(EVP_PKEY *key, const std::string& name) {
    OSSL_PARAM *param_array;
    if (EVP_PKEY_todata(key, EVP_PKEY_PUBLIC_KEY, &param_array) == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("cannot read parameters");

    OSSL_PARAM *cur_param;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        cur_param = &param_array[i++];
        if (std::string(cur_param->key) == name) {
            auto data = GetParameterData(cur_param);
            OSSL_PARAM_free(param_array);
            return data;
        }
    } while (cur_param->key != nullptr);

    throw std::runtime_error("cannot find parameter with name \"" + name + '"');
}


std::vector<unsigned char> GetParameterData(OSSL_PARAM *param) {
    BIGNUM *bignum{nullptr};
    if(OSSL_PARAM_get_BN(param, &bignum) == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("cannot read bignum");

    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes;
    int new_size = BN_num_bytes(bignum);
    bytes.resize(new_size);
    BN_bn2bin(bignum, bytes.data());

    return bytes;
}
```

The problem is when I try to build new key from raw bytes using the same approach

```
// keys_ defined inside object
EVP_PKEY *keys_ {nullptr};

void SetPublicKey(const std::vector<unsigned char> &key) {

    auto param_bld = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_new();


    BIGNUM *bignum = BN_bin2bn(key.data(), (int)key.size(), nullptr);
    OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_BN(param_bld, key, bignum);

    // default rsa exponent
    OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_long(param_bld, "e", RSA_F4);

    auto parameters = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_to_param(param_bld);
    OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free(param_bld);


    auto ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, nullptr);
    if (EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init(ctx) <= 0)
        /*error*/

    EVP_PKEY_free(keys_);
    if (EVP_PKEY_fromdata(ctx, &keys_, EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR, parameters) <= 0)
        /*error*/

    OSSL_PARAM_free(parameters);
}
```

for some reason, function EVP_PKEY_fromdata() fails to create new key using my OSSL_PARAM array. What am I supposed to do to initialize ONLY public key on signature verifying end (where I cannot build full keypair with all parameters) ?

you can see full source code for this class at https://github.com/Valemos/course_work_inverted_index/blob/master/src/session/RSAKeyPair.cpp

Comment: You are specifying EVP_PKEY_fromdata with the selection enum "EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR" so the API is trying to create both the private and public RSA keys. You've only supplied N and e in your params struct, so it can't do that. To create just public key you need to use EVP_PKEY_PUBLIC_KEY